# negative weight cycle detection using dijkstra's algorithm

Tags: graphs

Can we store a struct in place of vertex.
struct {
int v, update_count;
}

run dijkstra's algorithm and whenever a node is updated we will increase update_count value. If update_count value is greater than V(no of nodes) we will know that there is negative weight cycle. Is this a viable solution.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 2):

No. In a graph with $n$ nodes, Dijkstra's algorithm never updates a node more than $n-1$ times, so your test will never change anything. More fundamentally, negative-weight edges or cycles don't cause Dijkstra to get into infinite loops; they just make it give wrong answers in some cases.

This [answer on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13159337/why-doesnt-dijkstras-algorithm-work-for-negative-weight-edges) gives more detail.